# Does initiazling a variable waste compute if you are deserializing it using common deserialization libraries

Tags: c#, .net

For example if I am using system.text.json and I have a class:

```
public class CurrencyItem : UserDDBItemInstance
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Currencies { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();
}
```

Does this dictionary get created and then thrown away when deserialization does its magic?

Comment: it will overwrite the initialized value. it will not waste compute

Comment: The chances that *this* will be the bottleneck in your application, performance wise, is so close to zero to be treated as zero.

Comment: You can test this yourself by putting a breakpoint on the `get` and `set` methods (easiest way is to put the `get` and `set` on their own lines and then put a breakpoint on each of them). Then examine the call stack when these breakpoints are hit to see if your particular serialization scenario is `set`-ing the value to a new dictionary, or just `get`-ing the value (presumably to update the existing dictionary).

Comment: @letsdoit this isn't a scenario where a single definitive answer applies

Answer (score 4):

There is no single answer to this; it will depend on the serializer implementation and configuration. Some will spot the `set` and pre-emptively replace the collection completely; some may only use the `set` if they discover a `null` value, otherwise calling `.Clear()` or just add new data ignoring pre-existing values completely. Some may offer all these options or more via configuration. Some may skip the constructor in the first place, so the field initializer doesn't even run when using the library,

Source: am serializer implementer.

Comment: For information: I tried the .NET 7 System.Text.Json serialiser, and it does NOT optimise this case - but NewtonSoft's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` DOES optimise it. Which completely proves your point.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I could also point to multiple different ways of configuring protobuf-net for other examples - specifically `OverwriteList`, `SkipConstructor`, etc

Comment: Wow what great responses guys! Thanks so much for the input and inspection! Also Marc Gravell, this guy has written at least 2 SDKs that I use. Nice to see you here.